# How to transform child widgets in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want animate widgets like the below gif
[image: gif]

But whats happening is like the below gif

[image]

I just added a color to the container to get a sense of the frame of parent container

How can we make the inner widgets to clip when moving out of parent widget?

I am using Transform to animate like projects.

Please let me know if any more info is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your red container to clip overflow, you have to wrap it into a `ClipRect`.

```
new ClipRect(
   child: new Container(color: Colors.red, child: myAnimationThing),
),
```